# Highmaps Flight Routes add arrows

Tags: highcharts, routes, arrows

I'm using Highmaps and new topojson file to create a map with visualization of flight routes.
It's working well, see demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/L2ogczjh/
Now I need to add arrows on the maplines to indicate the way (city from -> city to). This arrow should be in the middle of the line (or just before the arrival mappoint).

I tried to use the following snippet seen in an post without success :

```
events: {
      load: function () {
        this.renderer
          .definition({
            tagName: 'marker',
            id: 'markerArrow',
            refY: 5,
            refX: 9,
            markerWidth: 11,
            markerHeight: 11,
            orient: 'auto',
            children: [{
              tagName: 'path',
              d: 'M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 Z',
              fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
              'stroke-width': 1,
              stroke: '#000000'
            }]
          });
      }
    }
```

Can you help me to do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the series you can implement a new type with a drawn arrow. Possible two approaches, write an arrow in the path, or draw a line and inside the CSS style add `marker-start: url(#tail);`.

```
      {
        type: 'mapline',
        colorAxis: false,
        name: 'Lines',
        color: 'black',
        data: [{
          name: 'line1',
          //path: 'M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 Z',
                    path: 'M 10 10 L 30 10',
          lineWidth: 3,
                    color: 'black'
        }]
      }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how I can add an arrow on each colored mapline already drawn on my map. Could you give me an example based on my demo please : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/L2ogczjh/ (I tried to add a css style on the mapline object without success). What I need on the demo example is to add an arrow on the Bangalore->Jakarta, Bangkok->Los Angeles, Baoding->Shanghai lines. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I forgot attach the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/80zyhgt1/.

Comment: Thanks for your demo, but it's not the result I expected. I need to draw an arrow on each mapline, the result should be as this : https://www.need4viz.com/dataviz/images/flight_arrows.png
The arrow can be in the middle of the line or at the end.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you any idea on how to achieve that please ?

Comment: There is still an option to edit the line geometry, but the solution is not very satisfying. [https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/80zyhgt1/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/80zyhgt1/1/)